# Which level of DevicePolicyManager password quality disables pattern password?

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

I am writing an android app which sets the password quality based on certain conditions. I can say with certainty that when password quality is set to PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING, the pattern password is available on the phone but when I set the password quality to PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHANUMERIC the pattern password is disabled on the phone. I just want to know which level of password quality disables the pattern password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `base/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java`, function `getActivePasswordQuality()`.

`PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING` and `PASSWORD_QUALITY_BIOMETRIC_WEAK` enables the user to choose a pattern, increasing password quality to `PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC` or greater would not allow pattern kind of password.

List of password qualities are defined in `base/core/java/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.java`

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, but here pattern has PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC (checking ActivePassworQuality >= PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC returns true).